# Error in lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following error:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type.

I can't resolve it.

```
delegate bool BoolPassword(string s1, string s2);
delegate bool Captha(string s1, string s2);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter password ");
    string password1 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Repeat password ");
    string password2 = Console.ReadLine();

    BoolPassword bp = (s1, s2) => s1 == s2;

    if (bp(password1, password2))
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        string resCaptha = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            resCaptha += (char)rand.Next(0, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter code " + resCaptha);
        string resCode = Console.ReadLine();

        Captha cp = (s1, s2) => // Error is here
            {                        
                if (s1 == s2)
                    Console.WriteLine("Ok");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("fail");                        
            };

        cp(resCaptha, resCode);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

Comment: What does your Captha delegate signature return? What doesn't your expression return?

Answer (score 4):

This code does not return a `bool` value as defined by your delegate

```
Captha cp = (s1, s2) => // Error is here
    {                        
        if (s1 == s2)
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("fail");                        
    };
```

---

You can fix this by doing:

```
Captha cp = (s1, s2) => // Error is here
    {                        
        if (s1 == s2)
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("fail");                        

        return s1 == s2;
};
```

or by amending your delegate signature:

```
delegate void Captha(string s1, string s2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your delegate to Gaptcha returns a bool, whilst your inline function does not. Change either your lambda to the following

```
Captha cp = (s1, s2) => // Error is here
{                        
    if (s1 == s2) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        retrurn true;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("fail");                        
        return false;
    }
};

var check = cp(resCaptha, resCode);
```

or the delegate-type to return void.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda expression is expected to return a bool. It does not. Either change the delegate signature or return a bool.

Answer (score 0):

You've stated in your code that the return type of the lambda is `bool` but you're not actually returning anything from your function.

```
delegate bool Captha(string s1, string s2)
```

If you want this to be your return type, you need to return something in all branches of the `if` statement.

```
Captha cp = (s1, s2) => // Error is here
            {                        
                if (s1 == s2)
                   return true;
                else
                   return false;                       
            };
```

You could also shorten this to `return s1 == s2;`

Comment: It's not really the return type of the lambda - the return type would have to be `bool`, as that's the return type of `Captha`.

Comment: ah yes. I missed the delegate declaration line at the top.